# Updateing multi-plot matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a problem witch updateing matplotlib chart. The problem is that i have many curve's on it, and after update the number of them may change. In example code I have 2 sets of data, 1st with 90 curves, and 2nd with 80, and i wish I could plot 1st set, and then 2nd, in the same matplotlib window.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.polynomial import RankWarning
import pandas as pd
import sys

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.78)
_x = []
_y = []
_y1 = []
_x1 = []
for x in range(90):
    _x.append(np.linspace(0, 10*np.pi, 100))
    _y.append(np.sin(_x[x])+x)
for x in range(80):
    _x1.append(np.linspace(0, 10*np.pi, 150))
    _y1.append(np.tan(_x1[x]+x))


def narysuj(__x, __y):

    p = []  # p-pomiar
    f = []  # f-czestotliwosc
    for x in range(len(__x)):
        p.append([])
        f.append([])
    ax.set_prop_cycle(color=plt.cm.gist_rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(__x))))
    for x in range(len(__x)):
        for line in range(len(__x[x])):
            #print(len(_y[x]), line)
            p[x].append(__y[x][line])
            f[x].append(__x[x][line])
        ax.plot(f[x], p[x], label=f"Label {x}")
    plt.show()


narysuj(_x, _y)
narysuj(_x1, _y1)
```

PS I know the way I'm drawing those charts is highly ineffective.

Comment: I have tried your code and the graphs do show up. Let's clarify what the issue is.

Comment: The Problem is that only graph form 1st call of narysuj() is showing up, I would like to see the 2nd one in this situation, and if I have added some delay between 1st and 2nd call, I would like to see the change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was the problem. I had to add plt.ion() at the start of program and ax.clear() before drawing.